# How to handle http response exception and continue the flow till aggregate in Spring integration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

I'm using Spring-integration in my project and the pattern used is scatter-gather. Here three parallel processes are being carried out. The flow2 is a outbound gateway method and if that service is down then I want to handle the Httpstatus exception and want to send null. Actually if that service is down then the whole flow is getting stopped. But I want to handle that exception and send null and then want to continue with the aggregate method and end the flow.

Below is the code - -

//Config file

```
 @Configuration
        public class IntegrationConfiguration {
          @Autowired LionsServiceImpl lionsService;
        
          long dbId = new SequenceGenerator().nextId();
      //   Main flow
      @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return flow ->
        flow.handle(validatorService, "validateRequest")
            .split()
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .scatterGather(
                scatterer ->
                    scatterer
                        .applySequence(true)
                        .recipientFlow(flow1())
                        .recipientFlow(flow2())
                        .recipientFlow(flow3()),
                gatherer ->
                    gatherer
                        .releaseLockBeforeSend(true)
                        .releaseStrategy(group -> group.size() == 2))
            .aggregate(prepareSomeRequest())
            .to(getDec());
  }

  //   Saving the request to the database
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow flow1() {
    return integrationFlowDefinition ->
        integrationFlowDefinition
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .handle(
                (payload, header) -> {
                  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                  try {
                    String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(payload);
                    JsonNode request = mapper.readTree(jsonString);
                    JsonNode csID = request.get("ApplicationDetails").get("CustomerId");
                    int customerID = mapper.treeToValue(csID, Integer.class);

                    return lionService.saveRequest(
                        payload,
                        String.valueOf(dbId),
                        customerID,
                        ((SourceSystem) Objects.requireNonNull(header.get("sourceSystem")))
                            .getSourceSystemCode());
                  } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                  }
                }
                )
            .nullChannel();
  }

  // 
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow flow3() {
    return integrationFlowDefinition ->
        integrationFlowDefinition
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .transform(
                message ->
                    loansService.someMethod(
                        (LionRequest) message));
  }

 //Here I'm calling a service through HTTPOUTBOUNDGATEWAY and if that called service is down then it throws HTTP STAtus error so I want to handle that and want to send null from this flow.
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow flow2() {
    return integrationFlowDefinition ->
        integrationFlowDefinition
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .handle(
                (payload, header) ->
                    loansService.someMethod2(
                        (LionRequest) payload,
                        (SourceSystem) (Objects.requireNonNull(header.get("sourceSystem")))))
            .handle(
                Http.outboundGateway(someurl)
                    .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                    .expectedResponseType(String.class)
                       );
  }


  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow getDec() {
    return flow ->
        flow.handle(
            Http.outboundGateway(ServiceURL)
                .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                .expectedResponseType(CrResponse.class));
  }


  @Bean
  public MessageChannel replyChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.executor("output-flow", outputExecutor()).get();
  }

  @Bean
  public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor outputExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    pool.setCorePoolSize(4);
    pool.setMaxPoolSize(4);
    return pool;
  }


//here I want to take out null from messages which is sent by flow2 if the called service is down and then I want to send null to someMethod2 method.

  public MessageGroupProcessor prepareSomeRequest() {
    return group -> {
      String cData;
      Object CDReq;

      List<Message<?>> messages = group.streamMessages().collect(Collectors.toList());

      ArrayList<Object> payloads = (ArrayList<Object>) messages.get(0).getPayload();

      if (payloads.get(0).toString().contains("tribv")) {
        cData= payloads.get(0).toString();
        logger.atInfo().log("Customer data from Data Sourcing Service : " + cData);
        CDReq= payloads.get(1);
      } else {
        cData= payloads.get(1).toString();
        logger.atInfo().log("Customer data from Data Sourcing Service : " + cData);
        CDReq = payloads.get(0);
      }

      Object fReq =
          lionservice.someMethod2(cData, CDReq);

      SomeRequest somreq= new SomeRequest();

      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

      JsonNode req = mapper.valueToTree(freq);
      creditDecisionRequest.setfsfgg(req);
      creditDecisionRequest.setR("234565432");
      creditDecisionRequest.setD(String.valueOf(dbId));
      creditDecisionRequest.setCID("33333333");
      creditDecisionRequest.setSourceSystemCode(SourceSystem.ONE.getSourceSystemCode());

      return somreq;
    };
  }
```

Gateway

```
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "flow.input")
  void processLionRequest(
      @Payload Message lionRequest, @Header("sourceSystem") SourceSystem sourceSystem);
```

Can I use something like `.errorHandler()` in the outboundgateway? But how do I use that?

```
 @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow flow2() {
    return integrationFlowDefinition ->
        integrationFlowDefinition
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .handle(
                (payload, header) ->
                    lionService.prepareSomeRequest(
                        (LionRequest) payload,
                        (SourceSystem) (Objects.requireNonNull(header.get("sourceSystem")))))
            .handle(
                Http.outboundGateway(someurl)
                    .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                    .expectedResponseType(String.class),
                c -> c.advice(expressionAdvice()));
  }



    @Bean
  public Advice expressionAdvice() {
    ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice =
        new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
    advice.setSuccessChannelName("success.input");
    advice.setOnSuccessExpressionString("payload + ' was successful'");
    advice.setFailureChannelName("failure.input");
    advice.setOnFailureExpressionString("Failed");
    advice.setReturnFailureExpressionResult(true);
    advice.setTrapException(true);
    return advice;
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow success() {
    return f -> f.handle(System.out::println);
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow failure() {
    return f -> f.handle(System.out::println);
  }

  public String adviceOnFailure() {
    return "Failed";
  }
```

I'm doing something like that but getting error as below -

[GenericMessage [payload=[org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'Failed' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage' - maybe not public or not valid?], headers={sequenceNumber=1, sequenceDetails=[[f596d446-9816-e13b-240c-f365338a5eb4, 1, 1]], replyChannel=nullChannel, sourceSystem=ONE, sequenceSize=1, correlationId=f596d446-9816-e13b-240c-f365338a5eb4, id=5592b1da-19fd-0567-c728-71b47d46b2d5, timestamp=1658382273446}]]

I want String "Failed" to be in the message, so that I can take that string and process further. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `null payload` concept in messaging, so even if you handle an error, you definitely cannot return `null` as a reply from that Outbound Gateway call.

See Request Handler Advice pattern in the framework, in particular an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` implementation. It does handle error for the specific message handler and may return a *compensation reply* which you then can aggregator and process respectively.

The doc is here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#message-handler-advice-chain

Comment: It's nothing like I need to send null only. I can return some String as well if the exception occurs then I can have a if else statement inside aggregator() method. So how can I just handle that exception and send a String or flag type just to indicate that exception has occurred?

Comment: I wonder why the doc I pointed in my answer doesn't meat your requirements...

Comment: Sorry but not able relate with my use case by seeing the documentation.

Comment: You want something like `try...catch` around your ` Http.outboundGateway()`. So, that is exactly what we do with the `AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice`. And the mentioned `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` is for your request. If you want, you can open its source code to determine how it works.

Comment: I'm using the same as u suggested. Kindly see the updated question and please suggest for the error that I'm getting here.

Comment: With that `adviceOnFailure()` you essentially make that String as a service. You probably want to calm that method against every message instead: `handle((p, h) -> return adviceOnFailure();)`

Comment: In case of httpoutbound success the flow is delegating to aggregate() but in case of failure it's exiting from the flow. Here I want to send some string in the payload and want to continue with the full flow i.e., aggregate(someMethod()).to(someMethod2()). Kindly advice.

Comment: See JavaDocs of the class I advised for your. It has this option `returnFailureExpressionResult`.

Comment: Hi @Artem, I have used the same as per your advice, but I'm not getting desired message. Kindly see my edited POST , there I've put the code.